# Pascal DLL has no functions

Tags: python, dll, export, ctypes, pascal

I've been goobing around with FreePascal and made a simple test DLL.

```
library dll;

function addstuff(onenumber, twonumber : Integer) : integer; stdcall;

begin
     addstuff := onenumber + twonumber;
end;


begin
end.

exports addstuff;
```

However, when I try to import it into Python using Ctypes, it claims that there is no function `addstuff` in the dll. The [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) says there are no functions in it at all either.

I can't seem to find any simple tutorials for building a DLL on the internet, so I'm most likely doing something stupidly wrong. Any tips? I'm pretty new to Pascal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the exports section outside the program, put it inside

```
library dll;

function addstuff(onenumber, twonumber : Integer) : integer; stdcall;

begin
     addstuff := onenumber + twonumber;
end;

exports addstuff;    

begin
end.
```